# Hyperledger through a business perspective

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

If a third party provides a set of organizations with a Hyperledger network using which those organizations can perform a certain set of transactions in a collaborative way with trust.

Then what are the ways in which the third party can earn money?

If the third party wants to take a commission on the transactions taking place between the different organizations then does it always need to be part of all the different channels?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems pretty unclear and out of context.

Hyperledger Network is a Permissioned Blockchain Network so, any third person cannot easily join the network, they need to be authorized by certain peers.

Also, About "commission on the transaction", Hyperledger Network is formed by the consortium of organizations so, why would there be commission on transactions.? Think About it! However, You can configure the Network however you like it.